# Twitter API callback integromat url

Tags: twitter-api-v2

I always get Twitter API response
"Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings"

but I changed Redirect CB URL in twitter API settings to required

"https://www.integromat.com/oauth/cb/oauth2"

What's wrong?

I've changed redirect url multiple times. IT doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

Use - `https://www.integromat.com/oauth/cb/twitter`

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: @starball I don't think so. OP is also using Integromat and the answer points to a different API.